# Netty connection becomes inactive after 30 seconds

Tags: java, netty

I am trying to make a netty connection for a project and I am successfully able to make it. However, after 30 seconds the connection becomes inactive. I'm purposefully not using the connection for something because it is a test connection but I want to keep it active for future tasks even after 30 seconds are over. This is my code to create the connection:

```
try {
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true);
        b.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
        b.group(new NioEventLoopGroup());
        b.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
        b.handler(new ReadTimeoutHandler(50));

        InetSocketAddress sa = new InetSocketAddress("--------IP HIDDEN--------", 25454);
        ChannelFuture f = b.connect(sa.getAddress(), sa.getPort()).sync(); // (5)
        Channel chan = f.channel();
        //Channel becomes inactive after 30 seconds
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Why do you add a `ReadTimeoutHandler`?

Comment: When I open a connection it requires a handler. In the real one there is a different handler but the class I use is part of a different library that doesn't come with Java. The same issue happens with the ReadTimeoutHandler so it's not a problem with the other Handler class.

Comment: what you mean with becomes inactive ? channelInactive is fired ?

Comment: Yes. When I run chan.isActive() it returns false. I'm not firing channelInactive. It gets fired automatically and I want to keep it from doing that.

Comment: If its fired automatically it means that the remote peer closed the connection. There is nothing we can do here. You may need to implement some kind of keep-alive logic.

Comment: But I created the connection so how would it be closed remotely? I’m new to all of this. Can you help me implement the keep alive logic?